# JavaScript toggle 2 links from full page

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I have a page full of links and they're paired. What I would like to do is once I've clicked a question mark (for help) the first 2 pairs are selected, then the next 2 and so on. The problem is that the links are created randomly on the page. I have the following code which selects the first link and its pair.

```
$(".main .container a:first").css("color", "#0c0");

var valid = $(".main .container a:first").attr("class").split(" ");
var links = $(".main .container a");

for (i = 0; i < links.length; i ++) {
    var attributes = $(links[i]).attr("class").split(" ");

    if (attributes[1] == valid[1]) {
        $(links[i]).eq(0).css("color", "#0c0");
    }
}
```

EDIT:

```
$(".help a").on("click", function()
{
    var unchecked = $(".main .container a:not(.selected)");
    var valid = unchecked.eq(0).attr("class").split(" ");
    var links = $(".main .container a");

    unchecked.eq(0).addClass("selected");

    for (i = 0; i < links.length; i ++) {
        var attributes = $(links[i]).attr("class").split(" ");

        if (attributes[1] == valid[1]) {
            $(links[i]).eq(0).addClass("selected");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you can simply manage that by adding a CSS class to the elements that were already "selected".

Check this simple test I did at JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L4rUM/1/

```
// When you click the "?"
$('button#btnHelp').on('click', function(){

     // Gathers the list of ALL <a> elements that were not "selected" yet
     var uncheckeds = $('.main .container > a:not(.selected)');

     // If you have at least 2 available elements
     if(uncheckeds.size() > 1){
         // Adds the .selected CSS class to first 2 non-selected elements
         uncheckeds.eq(0).addClass('selected');
         uncheckeds.eq(1).addClass('selected');
     }
 });
```

And the CSS manipulation you are doing is now controlled by just adding the CSS class:

```
.selected { color: #0c0; }
```

I hope this helps and solve your problem :)

Comment: I've edited my question as I'm almost there, but I keep on cycling through the first 2 links. Any help buddy?

Comment: Share your whole code (html, css and js) on JSFiddle so I can see what's really going on and do some tests.

Comment: I've marked this problem as solved as I can work with what I've got. I've taken out the first for loop so that now I can select multiple groups of links. Thanks for the solution mathielo.

Comment: Very nice! Glad you make through it :)